# Splitting plain text dictionary data to multiple files, round 2

Tags: python, algorithm, parsing

This is a continuation of [my earlier question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/59629/splitting-plain-text-dictionary-data-to-multiple-files/59688#59688).

I have a plain text file with the content of a dictionary ([Webster's Unabridged Dictionary](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/29765)) in this format:

> ```
> A
> A (named a in the English, and most commonly ä in other languages).
>
> Defn: The first letter of the English and of many other alphabets.
> The capital A of the alphabets of Middle and Western Europe, as also
> the small letter (a), besides the forms in Italic, black letter,
> etc., are all descended from the old Latin A, which was borrowed from
> the Greek Alpha, of the same form; and this was made from the first
> letter (Aleph, and itself from the Egyptian origin. The Aleph was a
> consonant letter, with a guttural breath sound that was not an
> element of Greek articulation; and the Greeks took it to represent
> their vowel Alpha with the ä sound, the Phoenician alphabet having no
> vowel symbols. This letter, in English, is used for several different
> vowel sounds. See Guide to pronunciation, §§ 43-74. The regular long
> a, as in fate, etc., is a comparatively modern sound, and has taken
> the place of what, till about the early part of the 17th century, was
> a sound of the quality of ä (as in far).
>
> 2. (Mus.)
>
> Defn: The name of the sixth tone in the model major scale (that in
> C), or the first tone of the minor scale, which is named after it the
> scale in A minor. The second string of the violin is tuned to the A
> in the treble staff.
>  -- A sharp (A#) is the name of a musical tone intermediate between A
> and B.
>  -- A flat (A) is the name of a tone intermediate between A and G.
>
> A per se Etym: (L. per se by itself), one preëminent; a nonesuch.
> [Obs.]
> O fair Creseide, the flower and A per se Of Troy and Greece. Chaucer.
>
> A
> A, prep. Etym: [Abbreviated form of an (AS. on). See On.]
>
> 1. In; on; at; by. [Obs.] "A God's name." "Torn a pieces." "Stand a
> tiptoe." "A Sundays" Shak. "Wit that men have now a days." Chaucer.
> "Set them a work." Robynson (More's Utopia)
>
> 2. In process of; in the act of; into; to; -- used with verbal
> substantives in -ing which begin with a consonant. This is a
> shortened form of the preposition an (which was used before the vowel
> sound); as in a hunting, a building, a begging. "Jacob, when he was a
> dying" Heb. xi. 21. "We'll a birding together." " It was a doing."
> Shak. "He burst out a laughing." Macaulay. The hyphen may be used to
> connect a with the verbal substantive (as, a-hunting, a-building) or
> the words may be written separately. This form of expression is now
> for the most part obsolete, the a being omitted and the verbal
> substantive treated as a participle.
>
> MALAY
> Ma*lay", n.
>
> Defn: One of a race of a brown or copper complexion in the Malay
> Peninsula and the western islands of the Indian Archipelago.
>
> MALAY; MALAYAN
> Ma*lay", Ma*lay"an, a.
>
> Defn: Of or pertaining to the Malays or their country.
>  -- n.
>
> Defn: The Malay language. Malay apple (Bot.), a myrtaceous tree
> (Eugenia Malaccensis) common in India; also, its applelike fruit.
>
> MALAYALAM
> Ma"la*ya"lam, n.
>
> Defn: The name given to one the cultivated Dravidian languages,
> closely related to the Tamil. Yule.
>
> MALBROUCK
> Mal"brouck, n. Etym: [F.] (Zoöl.)
>
> Defn: A West African arboreal monkey (Cercopithecus cynosurus).
> ```

I want to convert this file to a different format to make it easier and more efficient to search in it. This is the idea:

1. Split the file into a collection of entries
2. Save each entry in its own file:

   - Not all in the same directory (100k+ files), split to multiple subdirs
3. Create an index file

   - One line per entry, in the format: `FILENAME:WORD`

I implemented the suggestions in [@jcollado](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/8903/jcollado)'s excellent [previous answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/59688/12390), and made some other improvements:

- Refactored the functions, use `parse_content` generator to return `term, content` pairs
- Added a count for terms that appear multiple times, in the form of `-1`, `-2`, `-3`, ... appended (to display later by GUI apps as subscripts)
- Changed the directory splitting logic, because there were still hundreds of files in most output directories. For example now the word `greeting` will go in `g/gr/gre/greeting-NUM.txt` instead of `gr/greeting-NUM.txt`
- Replaced `OptionParser` with `ArgumentParser`
- Made it easier to debug, with the `--dry-run` and `--max-count` options
- Fixed some minor bugs

This is the script I'm using now:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python

import re
import os
import logging

from argparse import ArgumentParser

DATA_DIR = 'data'
INDEX_PATH = os.path.join(DATA_DIR, 'index.dat')

re_entry_start = re.compile(r'[A-Z][A-Z0-9 ;\'-.,]*$')
re_nonalpha = re.compile(r'[^a-z]')


def write_entry_file(dirname, filename, content):
    basedir = os.path.join(DATA_DIR, dirname)
    if not os.path.isdir(basedir):
        os.makedirs(basedir)

    path = os.path.join(basedir, filename)
    with open(path, 'w') as fh:
        fh.write('\n'.join(content) + '\n')


def is_new_term(line, prev_line_blank):
    return re_entry_start.match(line) and prev_line_blank and '  ' not in line


def parse_content(arg):
    prev_line_blank = True
    term = None
    term_count = 0
    content = []
    with open(arg) as fh:
        for line0 in fh:
            line = line0.strip()
            if is_new_term(line, prev_line_blank):
                if term:
                    for term in term.split('; '):
                        yield term, content
                prev_term = term
                term = line.lower()
                if term == prev_term:
                    term_count += 1
                    subscript = '-' + str(term_count)
                else:
                    term_count = 1
                    subscript = ''
                content = [term + subscript]
            else:
                content.append(line)
            prev_line_blank = not line


def get_split_path(term, count):
    slug = re_nonalpha.sub('_', term.lower()).ljust(3, '_')
    dirname = os.path.join(slug[0], slug[:2], slug[:3])
    filename = '{}-{}.txt'.format(slug, count)
    return dirname, filename


def parse_file(arg, dry_run=False, max_count=0):
    def rebuild_index():
        count = 0
        for term, content in parse_content(arg):
            count += 1
            if max_count and count > max_count:
                break
            dirname, filename = get_split_path(term, count)
            entry = '{}/{}:{}'.format(dirname, filename, term)
            logging.info(entry)
            if not dry_run:
                fh.write(entry + '\n')
                write_entry_file(dirname, filename, content)

    if dry_run:
        rebuild_index()
    else:
        if not os.path.isdir(DATA_DIR):
            os.makedirs(DATA_DIR)
        with open(INDEX_PATH, 'w') as fh:
            rebuild_index()


def main():
    parser = ArgumentParser(description='Generate index and entry files '
                                        'from cleaned plain text file')
    parser.add_argument('--dry-run', '-d', '-n', action='store_true',
                        help="Dry run, don't write to files")
    parser.add_argument('--max-count', '-c', type=int,
                        help="Exit after processing N records")
    parser.add_argument('files', help="File(s) to parse", nargs='+')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO,
                        format='%(levelname)s: %(message)s')

    for arg in args.files:
        parse_file(arg, dry_run=args.dry_run, max_count=args.max_count)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

It creates an index file like this:

> ```
> a/a_/a__/a__-1.txt:a
> a/a_/a__/a__-2.txt:a
> a/a_/a__/a__-3.txt:a
> a/a_/a__/a__-4.txt:a
> a/a_/a__/a__-5.txt:a
> a/a_/a__/a__-6.txt:a
> a/a_/a__/a__-7.txt:a-
> a/a_/a__/a__-8.txt:a 1
> a/aa/aam/aam-9.txt:aam
> a/aa/aar/aard_vark-10.txt:aard-vark
> a/aa/aar/aard_wolf-11.txt:aard-wolf
> a/aa/aar/aaronic-12.txt:aaronic
> a/aa/aar/aaronical-13.txt:aaronical
> a/aa/aar/aaron_s_rod-14.txt:aaron's rod
> a/ab/ab_/ab_-15.txt:ab-
> a/ab/ab_/ab_-16.txt:ab
> a/ab/aba/abaca-17.txt:abaca
> a/ab/aba/abacinate-18.txt:abacinate
> a/ab/aba/abacination-19.txt:abacination
> a/ab/aba/abaciscus-20.txt:abaciscus
> a/ab/aba/abacist-21.txt:abacist
> ```

Although I like it much better than the previous version, but as I've made significant changes, I'm wondering:

- Any new mistakes I added?
- Anything else I can still do better?

The full input file (cleaned data) is [here](http://data.janosgyerik.com/pub/webdict/wud/clean.1.gz) (10 MB download, 27 MB unzipped).

The open-source project is on [GitHub](https://github.com/janosgyerik/dictgen).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code looks good and it's been improved in multiple ways (argparse, index file opened just once, dry-run flag instead of debug one, ...). Hence, this review is going to focus in small details:

- Please add docstrings to document the code. This will make the code more readable and make easier to potential collaborators in github to join the project.
- Try to order the imports alphabetically. Not really needed, but is a nice touch.
- For a better separation of concerns, `write_entry_file` shouldn't take care of joining `content`. This should happen earlier in `parse_file`.
- The `count` variable in `rebuild_index` seems to be a good candidate for `enumerate`:

  ```
  for count, (term, content) in enumerate(parse_content(arg)):
  ```
- The `dry_run` check is in a couple of places in `parse_file` and might be confusing at first. What about something like:

  ```
  def parse_file(arg, dry_run=False, max_count=0):
      def rebuild_index():
          count = 0
          for term, content in parse_content(arg):
              count += 1
              if max_count and count > max_count:
                  break
              dirname, filename = get_split_path(term, count)
              entry = '{}/{}:{}'.format(dirname, filename, term)
              logging.info(entry)
              yield entry, dirname, filename, content

      if dry_run:
          for _index_data in rebuild_index():
              pass
      else:
          if not os.path.isdir(DATA_DIR):
              os.makedirs(DATA_DIR)
          with open(INDEX_PATH, 'w') as fh:
              for entry, dirname, filename, content in rebuild_index():
                  fh.write(entry + '\n')
                  write_entry_file(dirname, filename, content)
  ```
- The argument parsing code should be in a separate function and `main` should take the arguments. This way, `main` is testable in case you want to write test cases in the future:

  ```
  if __name__ == '__main__':
      args = parse_arguments()
      main(args)
  ```